# Why is Label Placement Menu Different with Additional Data Frame in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, labeling, data-frame, maplex

This is the first time I've tried using multiple data frames in layout view of ArcMap 10.3.1.

I'm trying to label some counties, but the label placement options menu in this additional data frame is different with many, many fewer options than in the original data frame. I want to do a boundary placement in the new data frame, but there are zero options for doing so. What is happening here? I can't seem to find any info on here or through googling it.

This is the menu I get in the original data frame:

[image]

This is the one I get with the new data frame:
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turn on the "Labeling" toolbar. Check the box beside 'Use Maplex Label Engine', then you will get the first Placement Properties dialog box.

Also as PolyGeo mentioned, you can turn on Maplex in the Data Frame Properties.
[image]

There is an option to have **Maplex** labelling on by default. Customize, ArcMap Options, Data View, Default Labeling Properties, Label Engine --> Standard Label Engine -or- Maplex Label Engine.

Comment: You can also set the labelling engine from the Data Frame Properties by using the data frame's context menu.

Comment: Much appreciated, everyone! I had tried selecting the Maplex engine through ArcMap Properties, but it looks like I needed to do it through the Data Frame Properties. It's working now.

Answer (score -1):

Use Maplex engine fixed my problem.
If you use standard labeling engine, later on, when you publish it to arcgis server,
you  can not create custom labeling with arcgis online map viewer.

By using Maplex engine, you can create custom labeling with arcgis online map viewer.

As Mattropolis suggested, here is how I turn on Maplex engine on my arcmap and on my arcPro.

Arcmap First:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is esri document

Enabling the Maplex Label Engine and adding the Labeling toolbar

https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-text/enabling-maplex-for-arcgis-and-adding-the-labeling-toolbar.htm

How to turn on maplex at ArcPro

[image]

Warning:

Analyze does not identify the compatible issue !!!! Which it should.  Maybe is a bug need improvement.

ESRI never tell us that standard label engine will not compatible with arcgis online map viewer. You have to figure out on your own.

I have called esri customer service, they create a case with case number, however, they don't know what is wrong, don't know what to do, eventually they said they will escalate it to higher level team for further investigation.

[image]